# How can you accept the vcsa EULA via vapp property?

Tags: terraform, vsphere, powercli, terraform-provider-vsphere

Does anyone know of a way to accept the EULA when deploying a vcenter server appliance via ova using a vapp property?  I'm trying to deploy a vcsa 6.7 instance via terraform using the `vsphere_virtual_machine` resource with the `ovf_deploy` property to a remote ovf url.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was actually related to properties within the OVF that were set to `userConfigurable="false"`.  The terraform provider `vsphere_virtual_machine` resource already has the logic within it to accept the EULA.